# Using \eqref and labelling an equation in LaTex

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am trying to label an equation so I can refer to it later on in the text but the label will not show up. The reference later on in the text recognizes the reference but I actually need the (1) to show up next to my equation. I have tried changing position and using `\textit` but none of these have worked for me

On line 8 of the code after `\label{eq:1}`, no (1) appears on the PDF. How can I make it show?

```
    \begin{equation*}
t_{0,k} =
\left\{
    \begin{array}{11}
        1 & \text{if } k = 0\\
        0 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.**\label{eq:1}**
\end{equation*}\\
From equation \eqref{eq:1}................(this works fine)....
```

Comment: note that the argument of `\label` is unrelated to any number that is used for the equation. It is a bad idea to use labels like `eq:1` as that may make a human reader think that it is equation 1. the `\label` argument is just an internal identifier used for cross referencing.

Comment: also  don't use `\\ ` after `\end{equation}` the `\eqref{eq:1}` you comment works fine but it will be returning the current section number not an equation number, as you have used it in `equation*` which is unnumbered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The star form of environment `equation*` is not numbered, therefore the `\label` has no equation number to refer to. Using `equation` instead of `equation*` should fix the issue.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    t_{0,k} =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if } k = 0\\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

  From equation \eqref{eq:1} \dots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, how come you have used cases here and not array? Also why would we use the * option? This is the one I used from my notes so don't understand why it doesn't work. Sorry - I am quite new to LaTex

Comment: @harry55 `cases` is designed for just this purpose. And one doesn't always want or need to number all equations, and for the equations that shouldn't have a number you can use the starred version.

Comment: @harry55 For example, the documentation of `amsmath` is available as [`amsldoc.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf). Environment `equation*` is explained in section "3.2 Single equations", and environment `cases` is shown in section "3.7 Alignment building blocks".

Comment: @TorbjørnT I understand the * now, that's clear. But even just using \begin{equation} with the array commands, it still did not work. My notes only provide me with the array option not the cases so it would be good to know why the array option didn't work?

Comment: @harry55 The contents of the equation (`array` or `cases`) does not matter for the numbering. My example can be compiled, see, whether it works for you. Make a similar example for your case, that does not work.

Comment: @harry55 It does work with  `array`, but as I just noticed, you have used `1` (number one) instead of `l` (lowercase L), so that would cause an error. It's unrelated to the numbering though, as Heiko says.